# clang::ast_matchers::thisPointerType ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I am working on a project involving Clang AST matchers. This is one such AST matcher that I'm having.

```cpp
StatementMatcher getNumUses_matcher1 = binaryOperator(
    hasOperatorName(">"),
    hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(
        cxxMemberCallExpr(
            thisPointerType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(isSameOrDerivedFrom("Value")))),
            hasDeclaration(cxxMethodDecl(hasName("getNumUses")))
        )
    )),
    hasRHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(
        integerLiteral(equals(0))
    ))
).bind("type1");
```

I'm compiling the project on Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler. I checked, and the matcher looks syntactically ok. But the compiler complains.

```
cxxMemberCallExpr term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
thisPointerType more than one instance of overloaded function "thisPointerType" matches the argument list
thisPointerType 'clang::ast_matchers::thisPointerType': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

[image]

[image]

So it seems that this is a compiler syntax error. But here's the strange part.

**Whenever I run this exact same ast matcher through `clang-query` it just works! `clang-query` also checks the syntax, but here there is no syntax error being reported. It runms the ast matcher and successfully matcher the desired expressions as expected.**

```
clang-query> match binaryOperator(hasOperatorName(">"),hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(cxxMemberCallExpr(thisPointerType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(isSameOrDerivedFrom("Value")))),hasDeclaration(cxxMethodDecl(hasName("getNumUses")))))),hasRHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(integerLiteral(equals(0)))))

Match #1:

C:\work\sample_example\sample_example.cpp:77:9: note: "root" binds here
        pGlobalVar->getNumUses() > 0
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I try to compile the same code with `clang++` compiler:

```
ReplaceGetNumUses.cpp:62:17: error: call to 'thisPointerType' is ambiguous
                thisPointerType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(isSameOrDerivedFrom("Value")))),
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\clang_llvm\llvm-project-master\clang\include\clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h:3741:43: note: candidate function
AST_MATCHER_P_OVERLOAD(CXXMemberCallExpr, thisPointerType,
                                          ^
C:\clang_llvm\llvm-project-master\clang\include\clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h:3749:43: note: candidate function
AST_MATCHER_P_OVERLOAD(CXXMemberCallExpr, thisPointerType,
                                          ^
```

Comment: are you sure `clang-query` is updated? maybe change the `<` to '>' and run again just to be sure ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I don't understand what is your suggestion. The operator name has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think you're running an out-of-date `clang-query` ... just make sure it really compiles ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `clang-query` accepts the AST matcher above, while both `clang++` and Microsoft Visual Studio `cl` compiler mark it as a syntax error. I found a solution though.

I restructured my AST matcher. I used a slightly different syntax for it. Now this one compiles, and also `clang-query` accepts it, generating the same results as the AST matcher above.

```cpp
StatementMatcher getNumUses_matcher1 = binaryOperator(
    hasOperatorName(">"),
    hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(
        cxxMemberCallExpr(hasDeclaration(cxxMethodDecl(
            hasName("getNumUses"),
            ofClass(isSameOrDerivedFrom("Value"))
        )))
    )),
    hasRHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(
        integerLiteral(equals(0))
    ))
).bind("type1");
```

Now in this approach I search for the name of the class by applying an `ofClass()` to the `cxxMethodDecl()` instead of using a `thisPointerType()` on the `cxxMemberCallExpr()`.

The problem may be in that `thisPointerType()` has two overloads. According to the [AST Matcher Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html#traversal-matchers).

```
Return type                 Name             Parameters

Matcher<CXXMemberCallExpr>  thisPointerType Matcher<Decl> InnerMatcher

Matcher<CXXMemberCallExpr>  thisPointerType Matcher<QualType> InnerMatcher
```

But I don't know enough about this to say for certain. Can anyone explain to me why that is?

Comment: Just had the exact same issue with `callExpr(callee(anyOf(..., ...))`, with `callee()` having the same abiguous overload error. According to the AST Matcher Reference page for `callee()`: `Callee cannot take the more general internal::Matcher<Expr> because this introduces ambiguous overloads [...] the matcher hierarchy is purely implemented in terms of implicit casts.` So I suppose what happened to you was that the type matched by `hasDeclaration()` could be implicitly casted to `QualType`, or something like that. Solution for me was `callExpr(anyOf(callee(...), callee(...)))`